# Create user in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core

I try to add list of users with seedata. But only the Admin is added from this list, which is the first in the list. Maybe you know another method?

```
if (!_roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(SD.Role_Admin).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
{
    _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(SD.Role_Admin)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(SD.Role_User)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    // Create Admin
    _userManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = "admin@gmail.com",
                    Email = "admin@gmail.com",
                    Name = "Admin",
                    PhoneNumber = "+380000000000",
                    StreetAddress = "Street 2",
                    State = "State",
                    PostalCode = "100000",
                    City = "City Name"
                }, "Admin123*").GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    ApplicationUser user = _db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == "admin@gmail.com");

    _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, SD.Role_Admin).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    // Create User1
    _userManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = "user@gmail.com",
                    Email = "user@gmail.com",
                    Name = "User",
                    PhoneNumber = "+3801111111",
                    StreetAddress = "Street 2",
                    State = "State",
                    PostalCode = "10000",
                    City = "Cuty Name"
                }, "User123*").GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    ApplicationUser user1 = _db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == "user@gmail.com");
    _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user1, SD.Role_User).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

I get this error :

[image: error]

It will be interesting to hear the opinion of other methods of seedusers

Comment: Looks like `user1` is `null`. Doesn't seem to be a user-related or seed-related issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should always the async and await keywords when using *Async* methods and use them all the way up, otherwise you should not use them.

You are calling an asynchronous operation and blocking on it synchronously with *task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()* which not only makes it very complicated but also not asynchronous and may lead to deadlocks.

What you might solve your issue is to change the seeding method to *async* and await the Add and Create methods.